# How to stop pidgin to run at Ubuntu start up?

Tags: pidgin

When I turn on laptop, with Ubuntu 12.04 installed, Pidgin Internet messanger appears in the list of the little letter from the right of the screen, up.

I don't want pidgin start by itself. I want to start it myself and stop it myself.

How?

Answer (score 1):

Is it listed in

> System > Preferences > Startup Applications

Comment: ok, thank you for answering. And how can I access that system etc? I'm a beginner.....sorry.

Comment: ok, I found Startup applications preferences....but it is empty !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> (windows key), search for Startup Applications and open it. If you see pidgin there, deselect it.
2. If don't follow next steps:

   - open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run next command (that show hidden startup aplications):
     `sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`
   - reopen Startup Applications as in step 1.
   - now you should see for sure pidgin, deselect it.

Also, this video should be helpful: [Tricks to Speed Up Ubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwBoHZuauL8).

Comment: Radu, thank you. I saw the list but Pidgin was not in it. I looked twice. But Pidgin appears in the list of the little envelope sign, up and right on the screen. Is it a bug?

Comment: @user153959 Did you follow step 2?